# Access query returning duplicate rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

A similar question had been asked multiple times, but none of the answers help in this situation, so asking the question again.

I have 3 tables Customers, invoices,inv_pay.
I want to create a query that returns (customer id from customers table) AND (Final_money from invoices table) AND (amount from inv_pay table).

the problem is when I run the query I get Duplicated rows from the 2 tabes.
My tables :

Table Customers data :

`ID  cname  ccity  cdate
248  marcos city   03/11/2019`

Table invoices data :

`ID cust_id Final_money  ddate
1     248   ₪10,000      19/03/2020
2     248   ₪5,000       19/03/2020`

Table inv_pay data :

`ID  cust_id  amount  ddate
695   248    ₪5,000  19/03/2020
696   248    ₪2,500  19/03/2020`

Query-> SQL :

`SELECT Customers.ID, invoices.Final_money, inv_pay.amount
FROM (Customers LEFT JOIN inv_pay ON Customers.ID = inv_pay.cust_id) LEFT JOIN invoices ON Customers.ID = invoices.cust_id
GROUP BY Customers.ID, invoices.Final_money, inv_pay.amount;`

The result I get from the query:

`ID Final_money amount
248 ₪5,000      ₪2,500
248 ₪5,000      ₪5,000
248 ₪10,000     ₪2,500
248 ₪10,000     ₪5,000`

How can I Get query record without duplicated rows, What I want is:

`ID Final_money amount
248 ₪5,000      ₪2,500
248 ₪10,000     ₪5,000`

Only the records from the invoices table and the inv_pay table.

the relationship between the 3 tables is Customer Id (ID in table Customers )(cust_id in invoices and pay_inv) 1 to many.

All that I'm trying to do is get the sum for final_money and the sum for inv_pay for all customer invoices values and payment values.

Comment: How are you deciding what value to choose for `amount`?

Comment: I want to retrieves all the amount values for the customer by customer id, the final need is to build query sum all the final_money and all the amount for customers from invoices table and inv_pay table.

Comment: Can't with that query. Build a query that does Sum of inv_pay and join to that query.

Comment: As @RabeeaQabaha asked, how should Access know which pay_inv goes with which invoice? Your example output makes no sense.

Comment: @June7 then what the best way to accomplish that ??
All that I'm trying to do is get the sum for final_money and the sum for inv_pay for all customer invoices values and payments values.

Comment: Ooops, should have been "as @GordonLinoff asked". I already made a suggestion. Could also maybe build report/subreport.

Comment: @June7 I created query to sum amount if pay_inv and joined it to a query for customers data and the sum for final_money from invoices table and its working now.
the question now is this way effects the performance?